# Why is angular momentum equal to mass times radius times velocity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, angular-momentum

When momentum is mass times velocity, why is angular momentum mass times radius times velocity?

Comment: What do you mean by "why" here? Are you asking why this definition is *useful*? Are you asking whether this expression for angular momentum can be derived from some other definition? Something else?

Comment: What I mean by "why" is that why does angular momentum depend on radius when momentum is a quality (for lack of a better word) of mass and velocity, how would the distance from the object around which "our" object is rotating effect it's momentum? And I specifically used the word "why" because I wanted a more intuitive understanding than a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

> When momentum is mass times velocity, why is angular momentum mass times radius times velocity?

**High-school summary**

We are interested in both angular momentum and linear momentum because they are each conserved. They are different quantities because they come from different conservation laws, and the formula for each reflects the thing that is conserved.

**Mathematical derivation**

Momentum is the conserved quantity you get due to translational symmetry. In Cartesian coordinates the Lagrangian for a free particle is $$L=\frac{1}{2}m \dot x^2 $$ and the translational symmetry is seen by the fact that $L$ is not a function of $x$. So $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}=m \dot x= m v=p_x=const.$$

Angular momentum is the conserved quantity you get due to rotational symmetry. In polar coordinates the Lagrangian for a free particle is $$L=\frac{1}{2} m \dot r^2 + \frac{1}{2} m r^2 \dot \theta^2$$ and the rotational symmetry is seen by the fact that $L$ is not a function of $\theta$. So $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta} = m r^2 \dot \theta = m r v= p_\theta = const.$$

So they are different because they arise from different symmetries.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but do you really need Lagrangians to understand the definition of angular momentum?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I cannot think of another way that derives both angular momentum and linear momentum from the same process. So yes, I think you really do need Lagrangians to understand *why* they are each defined the way they are and why they are different

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a more intuitive explaination not mathematical because I'm a high school student and wouldn't understand such complex concept

Comment: @RoselynnSprinkles no problem, I added a high-school level summary at the top. I still kept the derivation since it will be useful to other students and since your question didn't explicitly identify your desired level. In the future, if you want things answered at a particular level that information should be explicitly stated in the question itself

Comment: I must admit I don’t have a better answer than you as to why but I’m not sure about invoking Lagrangians.  If anything your example does not contain any potential whereas angular momentum is conserved in the central case.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way possible, they are two different quantities. Linear momentum is not the same as angular momentum. They have similar names because they’re both conserved quantities, and angular moment is, in a sense, the rotational dynamics version of linear momentum. This also qualitatively explains why there’s the extra radius term.

Answer (score 0):

The linear momentum of a system is conserved in the absence of a net external force.  The angular momentum of a rotating object is conserve in the absence of a net external torque.  That is reflected by the formula: τ = dL/dt.  For a point mass moving in a circle, L = Iω = (m$r^2$)(v/r) = mvr.  In general, the definition of, L, gets more complicated, but conservation still requires no net torque.
Here's my favorite definition of torque:  Torque is the work done per unit angle of rotation (as in J/radian) that may be done by a force which is acting in a manner that tends to cause a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Rotational distance from the center effects momentum because it effects the velocity. A mass rotating 100RPMs with radius x will have more energy if the radius is 2x because it changes the circumference. If the RPMs stay the same then the mass needs to move faster in order to travel the longer circumference.
For example a 2lb mass moving at 100mph has a linear momentum of E=mv.
Take the same 2lb mass, still moving at 100mph and dived it into two 1lb masses connected by a solid rod and rotating 100RPMs at a 12" radius. The 2lb mass now has much more energy when you add the rotational energy to the already existing linear energy.
Now take the same set up and increase the radius or increase the RPMs and the total energy increases.